# Are length and time mathematically equivalent scales?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, speed-of-light, dimensional-analysis

So, say we define a clock as measuring an electronic oscillation on a quartz atom, eg, a normal clock.

The fine structure constant is a relation between the electron mass and C. If C goes up, electron mass goes up for a fixed alpha.

It's technically not based on the electron mass, but if the mass to charge ratio is fixed, then charge and mass are proportional and have the same behavior.

In mathematical terms,

Alpha = 1/4piEo * e2/hc

There is also

KE = mv2

Which suggests that higher mass would reduce velocity, but that means the time unit has to get larger which we do next.

The oscillation of the quartz atom has a velocity. If velocity goes down the oscillations get longer and the same time unit represents more time. As a result increasing mass also lengthens time for a fixed KE. As a result we can lengthen time all we want by increasing the mass unit and have no effect on kinetic energy.

If mass is increased then the only other consequence of mass is gravity and momentum. Again, the mass will move slower as a result, but our time unit is now also slower so there is no effect on KE.

So does this prove length and time are mathematically equivalent, IE, scale dependent? We can make light faster without limit by increasing the wavelength but the frequency remains the same, and if the time unit is slower then frequency represents a smaller unit so every equation is mathematically the same.

Comment: Your reasoning is all over the place. c is not something you change. Good physicists should measure time and space with the same length = time units, but not because of the reasoning you gave.

Comment: Thats not a refutation

Comment: What is even there to refute? You wrote down a (tolerably) wrong version of an approximation to kinetic energy, i.e. not fundamental to the universe, and quoted the fine structure constant, the only sensible thing in your entire thing that has a physical meaning, and then claimed that the constant c can change. If you learnt some dimensional analysis, you would know that c comes out only because we are using stupid unit systems. All appearances of c will disappear when we use good units, where c = 1. There is nothing to change.

Comment: *The fine structure constant is a relation between the electron mass and C.* The electron mass doesn’t appear in the fine structure constant.

Comment: Yes it does in the numerator.

Comment: If your only objection is lack of a natural unit system then I'll accept that.

Comment: No. The numerator is $e^2$.

Comment: Noted and fixed.

Comment: *charge and mass are proportional* They are not, in mainstream physics. The premise of your question is false.

Answer (score 1):

> So does this prove length and time are mathematically equivalent, IE, scale dependent?

No. What it proves is that the dimensionful physical constants only define our system of units. The actual physics is contained in the dimensionless constants.

Therefore, with

> If C goes up, electron mass goes up **for a fixed alpha.** (emphasis added)

you have ensured that all of the experimental results will remain the same regardless of how you change the other parameters.

My favorite article on this topic is here:

https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/constants.html